# Creating a Home Page Template

Tags: 7, theming

The index page of a site I am building is to be a video and nothing else which clicks through to the site.

I have read about page templates and seen some modules called 'front page' but I would like to to do this within the code.

Is there a best advised / standard way to do this?

I have tried setting an if statement for $front_page but this seems to happen for every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable you wish to test is $is_front, which is only true for the front page.

You can find a list of the variable available for page.tpl.php [here](http://drupal.org/node/1728148).

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /homepages/3/d423004562/htdocs/clients/thommurphy/drupal/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/templates/page.tpl.php on line 4

Comment: You probably have a missing close bracket just before line 4.

Comment: @KevinHowbrook, its a PHP err..